# Separate the rows returned by the date

Tags: javascript, html

I intend to separate the lines returned by the date.
So the idea is, all the lines returned from the 23rd, put the date before the first line and put all the lines in a row, then when the date is 24, then put the date back and return all the lines followed by the date 24 and so on.

I'm trying this way.

HTML:

```
<table id="alerta" class="table table-action table-striped table-hover responsive" style="width:100%">

    <tr> 
        <th>De</th>
        <th>Assunto</th>
        <th>Prioridade</th>
        <th>Recebido</th>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
        <th><td>Recebido</td></th>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>        
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>                                       
    </tr>

</table>
```

I return the data this way and create the pivot table:

```
$(function () { 
$.getJSON('./alertas', function (data) {
     
    var linha = ``;
    
    var arrayLength = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) { 
       Id = data[i][0];
       De = data[i][1];
       Assunto = data[i][2];
       Conteudo = data[i][3];
       Prioridade = data[i][4];
       Hora = data[i][5];
       Data = data[i][6];
       
       var  nomede = data;

       if(nomede != data){
       linha += `<tr>      
       <td>${ Data }</td>        
       </tr>`
       }else{
       linha += `<tr>      
        <td></td>      
       </tr>`   
       }
       linha += `<tr >           
       <td>${ De }</td> 
       <td>${ Assunto }</td>
       <td>${ Prioridade }</td> 
       <td>${ Hora }</td> 
       </tr>`; 
    }
    $("#alerta tbody").html(linha);
}); 
});
```

But this way the `TR` with the column `Recebido` is always without the date.
I intend to the `TR` `Recebido` only receive date when it returns rows of different dates.

I leave here the json:

```
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

$result_curso = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para

ORDER BY Recebido Desc LIMIT 200");

$result_curso->execute();

$total_cursos = $result_curso->fetchColumn();

$quantidade_pg = 10;

$num_pagina = ceil($total_cursos/$quantidade_pg);

$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

$result_cursos = $conn->prepare("SELECT Id, De, Assunto, Conteudo, Prioridade, DATE_FORMAT(Recebido,'%H:%i') AS Hora, DATE(Recebido) AS Data,
Email, Tipo, raddb.Alertas.Para, Status FROM raddb.Alertas LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.ValAlertas
ON raddb.ValAlertas.IdSMS = raddb.Alertas.Id AND raddb.ValAlertas.Para = raddb.Alertas.Para

ORDER BY Recebido Desc limit $incio, $quantidade_pg");

$result_cursos->execute();

$json = [];
while($row=$result_cursos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
extract($row);

$json[]= [(string)$Id, (string)$De, (string)$Assunto, (string)$Conteudo, (string)$Prioridade, (string)$Hora, (string)$Data];
}

echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: This kinda makes no sense `var  nomede = data;

       if(nomede != data){`. Why do you expect `nomede` to not equal `data` if you have just assigned it to be `data`?

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko Yes it doesn't make sense. I have already changed the variable to empty, but so the date returns on all lines even if they are the same

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to `var arrayLength = data.length;` for `for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {` -  `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {` is good enough.

Comment: @iAmOren I already changed that part of the code

Comment: If you shared some example data it would be easier to provide an answer ...

Comment: @GirkovArpa I leave here the example of what is happening. either show the date on all lines or don't show the date. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxl4t.png) What I want is to only return the date before the first line returned and only put the date back when the date is different from the first date. This is the code I have. I just didn't put the code that queries the database

Comment: But that's asking me to transcribe it into `JSON` ...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but I thought you were creating an HTML table with the data?

Comment: @GirkovArpa And I'm writing a table with the data that comes from json. 
When writing the table with the data returned from json, I want you to create a three with the date, whenever the date is different. The data is already returned and writes the table. It just remains that you write to such a tr with the date whenever the date is different to separate the returned lines by date